# How to include exception details in a custom diagnostic warning?

Tags: c#, sourcegenerators

I've got a C# source generator, and I want to report a warning if an exception is thrown during the generation itself.

I can successfully raise a warning, with a description, however I can't find a way to include the further details, which I've seen in other warnings that are reported.

Here's what I've got so far:

```cs
[Generator]
public sealed partial class MyGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor UnexpectedErrorDiagnostic = new DiagnosticDescriptor(
        id: "MYCUSTOMID001",
        title: "Unexpected Error During Generation",
        messageFormat: "Error for object",
        category: "Design",
        DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, isEnabledByDefault: true);

    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            // Some logic, which might throw an exception
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(UnexpectedErrorDiagnostic, Location.None));
        }
    }
}
```

When this gets raised, the code and description are set correctly:

[image: Warning correctly shown in VS2022 Error List]

What I want to do though is include the exception details in this same diagnostic, so that the warning can be expanded, like I see with some other warnings:

[image: Warning in VS2022 Error List that is expanded showing further details]

I've tried setting the Properties property during Diagnostic.Create, but they aren't shown anywhere.

How do I include this further information in a custom diagnostic?

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing as `RS2000` is a little bit different thing. It's a diagnostic rule reported from a diagnostic analyzer. It utilizes the same `DiagnosticDescriptor` class, but it's handled differently for a source generator. For example, `DiagnosticAnalyzer` expects a derived class to provide a list of supported diagnostics (via `SupportedDiagnostics`).

#### Diagnostic report in `DiagnosticAnalyzer`

Here is a minimalist example of a diagnostics analyzer:

```cs
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class MyDiagnosticAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(
        id: "MYCUSTOMID001",
        title: "Unexpected Error",
        messageFormat: "Error for object",
        category: "Design",
        defaultSeverity: DiagnosticSeverity.Warning,
        isEnabledByDefault: true,
        description: "MYCUSTOMID001 long description. This line will be shown in the error list panel");

    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics => ImmutableArray.Create(Rule);

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.None);
        context.EnableConcurrentExecution();
        context.RegisterSyntaxTreeAction(AnalyzeAction);
    }

    private static void AnalyzeAction(SyntaxTreeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        // ...
        context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, Location.None));
    }
}
```

It reports a warning with expandable details used from the `Description` getter of a `DiagnosticDescriptor` instance:

[image: analyzer]

#### Diagnostic report in `SourceGenerator`

Although it works for diagnostic analyzers, it does not seem to work for source generators.

```cs
[Generator]
public sealed class MySourceGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
    }

    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        // ...
        var descriptor = new DiagnosticDescriptor(
            id: "MYCUSTOMID002",
            title: "Unexpected Error",
            messageFormat: "Error for object",
            category: "Design",
            defaultSeverity: DiagnosticSeverity.Warning,
            isEnabledByDefault: true,
            description: "MYCUSTOMID002 long description. This line will be shown in the error list panel");

        context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(descriptor, Location.None));
    }
}
```

As we can see, there is no `Description` shown in the message:

[image: generator-1]

---

#### Workaround (eh, not really)

You can still provide meaningful diagnostics details from a source generator using the `MessageFormat` property and passing correct format argument(s) to `Diagnostic.Create` later on.

Here is an example:

```cs
public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
{
    // ...
    var descriptor = new DiagnosticDescriptor(
        id: "MYCUSTOMID002",
        title: "Unexpected Error",
        messageFormat: "Error for object: {0}",
        category: "Design",
        defaultSeverity: DiagnosticSeverity.Warning,
        isEnabledByDefault: true);

    context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(descriptor, Location.None, "Exception long description, stack trace, etc."));
}
```

It will produce this message:

[image: generator-2]

But I understand that this is not exactly what you are looking for.